# Worse quality on Jabra Evolve 80 USB headphones when using microphone

Tags: 18.04, gnome, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I've started using Jabra USB headphones recently and all is nice and dandy except the fact that it downgrades the sound quality whenever I use the microphone, and then it restores itself back to normal after let's say 3 seconds of not using the mic.

It happens when:

- Gnome's Sound settings is opened
- I start using mic in a game
- OBS is opened
- etc.

I've noticed the following in `syslog` when the downgrade happens (this example comes from starting Sound Settings):

```
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=7176 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=7176 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 21 18:30:15 pc systemd[6867]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=7176 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=7176 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
May 21 18:30:15 pc org.gnome.Nautilus[7017]: Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
May 21 18:30:15 pc nautilus[24808]: g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:15 pc nautilus[24808]: Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Failed to load SPARQL backend: Key file does not have group “DomainOntology”
May 21 18:30:15 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
May 21 18:30:15 pc systemd[6867]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
May 21 18:30:15 pc nautilus[24808]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:15 pc nautilus[24808]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:15 pc nautilus[24808]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:15 pc nautilus[24808]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2312HM (DFP-3): connected
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2312HM (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL U2312HM (DFP-3): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
May 21 18:30:16 pc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7009]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
May 21 18:30:16 pc nautilus[24808]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:16 pc nautilus[24808]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:16 pc gnome-control-c[24856]: Couldn't find a stream from the active input
May 21 18:30:35 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=7176 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 21 18:30:35 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=7176 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 21 18:30:35 pc systemd[6867]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
May 21 18:30:35 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
May 21 18:30:35 pc org.gnome.Nautilus[7017]: Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
May 21 18:30:35 pc nautilus[24907]: g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:35 pc nautilus[24907]: Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Failed to load SPARQL backend: Key file does not have group “DomainOntology”
May 21 18:30:35 pc dbus-daemon[7017]: [session uid=1000 pid=7017] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
May 21 18:30:35 pc systemd[6867]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
May 21 18:30:35 pc nautilus[24907]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:35 pc nautilus[24907]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:35 pc nautilus[24907]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:35 pc nautilus[24907]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:42 pc nautilus[24907]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 21 18:30:42 pc nautilus[24907]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
```

This is what I get in `alsamixer` which doesn't change when the downgrade/upgrade happens:

[image]

`arecord --list-devices` for reference:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: MS [Jabra EVOLVE LINK MS], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Which changes to below when degraded (mark the `0/1` next to Jabra card 2 entry):

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: MS [Jabra EVOLVE LINK MS], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`aplay -l` which doesn't change when downgrade happens:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: MS [Jabra EVOLVE LINK MS], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`pulseaudio --dump-conf` for reference:

```
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-11.1/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = 
log-level = notice
resample-method = auto
avoid-resampling = yes
enable-remixing = yes
remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
lfe-crossover-freq = 0
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 4
default-fragment-size-msec = 25
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 200000
```

`lsusb` for reference:

```
Device: ID 0b0e:0305 GN Netcom 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0b0e GN Netcom
  idProduct          0x0305 
  bcdDevice            3.09
  iManufacturer           1 GN Netcom A/S
  iProduct                2 Jabra EVOLVE LINK MS
  iSerial                 3 0001C36F5F8208
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          280
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength          112
        bInCollection           2
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
        baInterfaceNr( 1)       2
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID              12
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x03
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x00
        bmaControls( 2)      0x00
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0402 Headset
        bAssocTerminal          4
        bSourceID               2
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             4
        wTerminalType      0x0402 Headset
        bAssocTerminal          3
        bNrChannels             1
        wChannelConfig     0x0000
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 5
        bSourceID               4
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x03
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (SELECTOR_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 9
        bNrInPins               1
        baSource( 0)            5
        iSelector               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             6
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               9
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            10
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               6 Sidetone
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                11
        bSourceID              10
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x03
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x00
        bmaControls( 2)      0x00
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      4 (MIXER_UNIT)
        bUnitID                12
        bNrInPins               2
        baSourceID( 0)          1
        baSourceID( 1)         11
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        bmControls         0x00
        iMixer                  0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           6
        bDelay                  0 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                20
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             1
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            4 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]         8000
        tSamFreq[ 1]        16000
        tSamFreq[ 2]        44100
        tSamFreq[ 3]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00c0  1x 192 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           1
        bDelay                  0 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                23
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            5 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]         8000
        tSamFreq[ 1]        16000
        tSamFreq[ 2]        32000
        tSamFreq[ 3]        44100
        tSamFreq[ 4]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00c0  1x 192 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     332
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0024  1x 36 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

---

**EDIT**

I've noticed that in `pavucontrol` I can see 2 modes for output+input for those headphones and both cause the distorted sound.

The other "only output" modes do not cause this effect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I believe I got the culprit. It seems that it's defined in the firmware.

I've managed to run `Jabra SDK demo` https://developer.jabra.com/site/global/sdks/linux/index.gsp (some sort of device config app that's available on Linux instead of fully flegded app to manage device configuration like Jabra has available for Windows and Mac)

And with that I've managed to read device configuration options and boom, there's `Optimize audio for music` which unfortunately for me is either:

- disable - downgraded audio quality at all times
- enable - good quality but worse when speaking, using microphone

Is it possible to override it somehow?
[image]